# gtk2hs textview find substring and color it

Tags: haskell, textview, gtk, gtk2hs

I've made a window in Haskell using GTK (gtk2hs library) and added a Text View to it. Now I'm trying to find a specific sub-string in the Text View buffer and change it's foreground color. How can I do that ?

Comment: [Snap some blocks together](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2009/08/04/9856634.aspx): [`gtk_text_buffer_get_text()` + `gtk_text_buffer_get_iter_at_offset()` + `gtk_text_buffer_apply_tag()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk2/stable/GtkTextBuffer.html). I don't know what the gtk2hs equivalents to these are. What are you trying to do?